# Capistrano 3: Doing a Git pull on the an existing deploy relese folder

Tags: capistrano3

- I was using Capistrano 3 to do a deploy of a PHP  app from my linux machine.
- All was working well until the machine I was using to do the deploy died.
- Now all I want is: On the Server when I used to deploy: do a git pull on the last deployed folder to get the changes I have.
- Any clue as to how this can be done.
- I see no .git folder in the last deployed release folder
- I do see repo, but running any command in it does not help.
- Please help, thx in advance.